# How can I make redundant and unnecessary sentences shorthand in javscript?

Tags: javascript

How can I make redundant and unnecessary sentences shorthand in javscript?

My code is below.

```
    //initialization
    document.querySelector('#categoryCheckNormal').checked = false;
    document.querySelector('#categoryCheckDisabled').checked = false;
    document.querySelector('#categoryCheckBlind').checked = false;
    document.querySelector('#categoryCheckEvacuation').checked = false;
    // If there is a classification, put a value
    if (res.eventData.property.normal) {
        document.querySelector('#categoryCheckNormal').checked = true;
    } else if (res.eventData.property.disabled) {
        document.querySelector('#categoryCheckDisabled').checked = true;
    } else if (res.eventData.property.blind) {
        document.querySelector('#categoryCheckBlind').checked = true;
    } else if (res.eventData.property.evacuation) {
        document.querySelector('#categoryCheckEvacuation').checked = true;
    }
```

By the way, the code is redundant and less readable.

I'm wondering how I can change this as a best practice!

Best Regards!

Comment: You can define a helper function which take id and state as paramter update checked state.

Comment: Please do edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751130/how-can-i-make-redundant-and-unnecessary-statement-shorthand-in-javscript) instead of deleting and re-posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably approach it with the following method.

1. Add [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to the input boxes that match your classifications.
2. Grab all the inputs at once with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
3. You can then have you reset function iterate over them and reset the checked status.
4. You can then [grab the classifications from the `property` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [iterate over them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement), and then for each create a selector from the property key, query that element, and set the checked status.

```js
// Get all the inputs
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

// Iterate over them and reset them
function reset() {
  inputs.forEach(input => input.checked = true);
}

reset();

// Get some data
const res={eventData:{property:{normal:true,disabled:false,blind:false,evacuation:true}}};

// Get the property object
const { property } = res.eventData;

// Get its entries
const entries = Object.entries(property);

// Finally iterate over those entries and update
// the inputs based the key of each entry
for (const [key, value] of entries) {
  const selector = `[data-id="${key}"]`;
  const input = document.querySelector(selector);
  input.checked = value;
}
```

```html
Normal: <input type="checkbox" data-id="normal">
Disabled: <input type="checkbox" data-id="disabled">
Blind: <input type="checkbox" data-id="blind">
Evacuation: <input type="checkbox" data-id="evacuation">
```

Comment: Why use `data-id`s instead of the normal `id`s that OP already had? Although I guess the really appropriate choice would be a `name` attribute on each input.

Comment: Just personal choice really. @Bergi